# Text does not appear when calling json file, but app does not break

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am a React Native newbie and after reading a tutorial, I am trying to pull in data from a local JSON folder I created in my code editor. When the screen comes up, no text or images appear, just the background - doesn't break. I am trying to call up the image and basic text info for a just a single profile page such as name and occupation for Homer Simpson. If anyone could help out, I would appreciate it or atleast guide me in the right direction so I can figure it out.

This is how I created the JSON Folder in RN:

```
//Characters.js   

 const characters = [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        occupation: "Nuclear Safety Inspector",
        imageurl:
          "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-character/Homer/swsb_character_fact_homer_550x960.png"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        occupation: "Stay-at-home mom",
        imageurl:
          "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/simpsons-character/Marge/swsb_character_fact_marge_550x960.png"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        occupation: "Student",
        imageurl:
          "https://assets.fxnetworks.com/cms/prod/shows/the-simpsons/photos/swsb_character_fact_bart_550x960.png"
      }
    ];
    export default characters;
```

This is how I imported the folder:

```
import TEMP_CHARACTERS from "../Data/Characters";
```

This is how I called it up in the render:

```
class HomerSimpson extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const characters = TEMP_CHARACTERS
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://backgrounddownload.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/simpsons-clouds-background-5.jpg"
          }}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
          <Image
          imageurl={characters.imageurl}
          ></Image>
          <Text
          name={characters.name}
          occupation={characters.occupation}
          />
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default withNavigation(HomerSimpson)
```

Comment: you need to make `characters[0].imageurl`. Because the character is an array or you are the loop through an array using the map function.

Comment: @VikashSaini I tried that, but no luck.  How would you  make the loop for a single character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which item imageurl you would like to show, since this is an array you have them numbered from 0 down, so first item would be characters[0].imageurl, second would be characters[1](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-voice-ul0mj).imageurl etc.

@edit
I did a simple example that works, check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-voice-ul0mj) out.

Comment: I tried that but no luck, no texting is appearing. I even added a style component to it to see if something would appear, but no luck.

Comment: @csb00 I have added an working example to the main post of mine, please have a look.